# Get count of populated items in mongoose and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want make paginaton for review for certain items . I am using mongoose for populating reviews for movies.

> movies.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).populate('review')

How can i return the count of populated reviews?

Comment: Can you describe your problem and schema in more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow  this code.

```
count: { $sum: 1 }
```

[MongoDB Count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)